# Dealing with weird connectors

Tags: connector

I recently got hold of an LED matrix that I would really like to use in a project. The problem I have is that it uses a 2mm (not 2.54mm) pitch pin header connection for which I can find no standard sockets close by. Making a pcb would be the next best option but by the time it gets fabbed and shipped my holidays will be over. Are there any secret tricks around that would allow me to solder this matrix onto veroboard?

Comment: The secret trick is to plan ahead and not wait for the last minute.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I was in your situation I would probably solder ribbon cable or individual wires to each pin and run to the board.  Or etch my own PCB.

Comment: ditto etch your own PCB

Comment: Being able to etch or otherwise make pcb's is handy. You won't be dependent on some company and long shipping times for every little bit. Otherwise it's time for dead-bug or Manhattan or some other improvised method.

Comment: Or, in a hurry, scalpel + copper-clad and whittle your own board.

Answer (score 6):

While you're probably way after your holidays, for anyone who stumbles upon this question - a fairly creative solution for dealing with 2mm rasters is to use a 2,5-to-3,5-inch HDD converter:

[image]

Note that this will only work on exposed pins, not with the shrouded connectors (unless it happens to be a 40-pin one).

Answer (score 3):

I see that Newark has some [2mm pitch development boards](http://www.newark.com/jsp/content/printCatalog.jsp?cat=c127&page=0368&display=single).
They also have a couple of boards (such as the Vector 8018 and [Vector 8028](http://www.newark.com/vector-electronics-technology/8028/pcb-prototyping-board/dp/16J0508)) that have a 0.1 inch pitch on the left and 2 mm pitch on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

You probably decided by now, but 2mm pitch board to board connectors are really quite common.  Newark stock the following [GCT sockets](http://www.newark.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=422+2203+200107+810103856+810049686&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=global+connector+technology&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_US&divisionLocale=en_US&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=422+2203+200107&mm=1000785||,1001228||,&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&autoApply=true&originalQueryURL=%2Fjsp%2Fsearch%2Fbrowse.jsp%3FN%3D422%2B2203%2B200107%26Ntk%3Dgensearch%26Ntt%3Dglobal%2Bconnector%2Btechnology%26Ntx%3Dmode%2Bmatchallpartial%26No%3D0%26getResults%3Dtrue%26appliedparametrics%3Dtrue%26locale%3Den_US%26divisionLocale%3Den_US%26catalogId%3D%26skipManufacturer%3Dfalse%26skipParametricAttributeId%3D%26prevNValues%3D422%2B2203%2B200107) between 2-10 circuits in single row and dual row, both thru hole and SMT options, these are all vertical sockets.

Newark also stocks 1.27mm and 1.00mm pitch board to board sockets too.